# Meaning of the words "evaluate joint density function (transformed) at the point $(x,y)$"

Tags: probability, statistics

> You are given that $X$ and $Y$ both have the same uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$, and are
>   independent.
>   $U = X + Y$
>    and $V =
> {X \over X + Y}$
>   .
>    Find the joint probability density function of
>   $(U, V)$ evaluated at the point $\left ({1\over 2}, {1\over 2} \right )$.

So far, I have used the fact that $X=UV$ and $Y=U-UV$ to set up the jacobian determinant and determine that the joint distribution of $(U,V)$ is $u$.

However, I am still confused by the meaning of "evaluate at the point  $\left ({1\over 2}, {1\over 2} \right )$", as I don't think  I have seen something like this before, or if I have I am not understanding it's application here. The correct solution happens to be $1 \over 2$.

Comment: If the joint density is $(u,w)\mapsto u$ then clearly $(1/2,1/2)\mapsto 1/2$.

Comment: Strictly speaking you cannot evaluate a density function at a point. Any function equal almost everywhere to a density function of  a random variable is also a density function for the same variable. However, the title talks about evaluating the distribution function, not the density.

Comment: IMV the question to evaluate the PDF at a point is a "stupid question" (not your fault of course). See the comment of @Kavi for that. Why not just asking to determine the PDF if on forehand it is clear that you cannot escape from doing so? Or formally even better: determine **a** (not "the") PDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is a function on a set $X$, and $x\in X$, the English phrase "evaluate $f$ at $x$" means "compute $f(x)$".

Here if $f$ is the probability density function on $[0,1]\times[0, 1]$, (*not* the distribution, which is a different object) then to evaluate $f$ at $(\frac12, \frac12)$ just means to compute $f(\frac12,\frac12)$.